# Calculating table in R with uneven length

Tags: r

I have to table of data in R

```
a =   Duration (-10,0] (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,10]
1        2       0        0          0        2
2        3       0        0         10        3
3        4       0       51         25        0
4        5      19      129         14        0
5        6      60      137          1        0
6        7      31       62         15        5
7        8       7       11          7        0
```

and

```
b =   Duration (-10,0] (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,10]
1        1       0        0          1      266
2        2       1        0         47      335
3        3       1       26        415      142
4        4       3      965        508        5
5        5     145     2535        103        0
6        6     939     2239         15        6
7        7     420      613         86       34
8        8      46       84         36       16
```

I wouold like to calculate b/a by matching the duration. I though of some thing like ifelse() but it does not work. Can someone please help me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Should a `merge` `by="Duration"` work for you?

Comment: merge is when you want to join the data table right? or is that also possible to calculate c<-b/a?

Comment: After the `merge` with `all = TRUE`, then do the `b/a`.  BTW, for Duration that are not in one of the datsets, the rows will be NA after the merge.  So, it will be dividing by NA for that row.

Comment: after merge i get one large table of 15 rows. I'm not sure how to get b/a from there

Answer (score 1):

Match the order and selection of b with a (in my example y with x). Then do the math.

```
x <- data.frame(duration = 2:8, v = rnorm(7))

y <- data.frame(duration = 8:1, v = rnorm(8))
m <- match(y$duration, x$duration)

ym <- y[m[!is.na(m)],]

x$v/ym$v
```

It does not work when x contains items that are not in y, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the following:

```
a <- a[-1]
b <- b[-1]

a <- a[order(a$Duration),]
b <- b[order(b$Duration),]
durations <- intersect(a$Duration, b$Duration)
b[b$Duration %in% durations,] / a[a$Duration %in% durations,]

  Duration   (-10,0]  (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5]  (0.5,10]
2        1       Inf       NaN        Inf 167.50000
3        1       Inf       Inf  41.500000  47.33333
4        1       Inf 18.921569  20.320000       Inf
5        1  7.631579 19.651163   7.357143       NaN
6        1 15.650000 16.343066  15.000000       Inf
7        1 13.548387  9.887097   5.733333   6.80000
8        1  6.571429  7.636364   5.142857       Inf
```

you may like to replace NaN and Inf values by something else.